# authorizenet md5 to sha512 update when using official sdk-python

Tags: python, authorize.net

I've got only simple question if I need to do anything else than update Python SDK, Authorize.Net provided, to cover all changes connected with md5 to sha512 update?
I expect not, but to be sure.

Thank you

Pavel Cisar

Comment: The MD5 hash is only used to verify a transaction are actually from Authorize.Net.Do you do that in your code?

Comment: No, not directly in our code, but I would expect that python lib do that verification in background. If not, so no problem with moving to sha512. I put it into dev plan so.

Comment: It won't do that verification unless you ask it to. But unless you are using the SIM or DPM APIs, *and* are using the MD5 hash to verify the response,this won't affect you. So based on your comment this is not an issue for you.